# How can I compute the loss of the generator externally before computing the final loss?

Tags: tensorflow, python, keras

Let's assume I would like to train a generative network. This network should back-propagate based on two loss functions. The second one (`input_XB`) is the transformation loss of the image (`A -> A'`), just using MSE. The first loss should be something else, for example, in case it's the distance of the Hue Channel of HSV between the two images (difference A(Hue)/A'(Hue)), or something completely different. That difference that I would need external preprocessing of the generator (`g_model_1`) output, with OpenCV, for example, before calculating the loss.

How can I achieve that? I think that using TensorFlow with gradient tape and low-level API stuff can probably help me with that. But is there any kind of shortcut, because my approach does not construct a proper graph, because I am not passing all inputs over the generator model.

```
def define_composite_model_B(g_model_1, image_shape,image_shape2):

  g_model_1.trainable = True

  # discriminator outsorced
  input_A = Input(shape=image_shape2)


  # transformation loss
  input_XB = Input(shape=image_shape)
  B_fake=g_model_1(input_XB)


  model = Model([input_A,input_XB],[input_A,B_fake])

  opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)

  model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy','mse'], optimizer=opt)
  model.summary()
  return model
```

Comment: What is your main question? Can you summarise your problem with one single question? See if the new title summarises your question. Anyway, I think this question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow or Data Science SE, so I may migrate it to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for ediditing my post, my main question is how to use preprocessing steps in the model itself. Its more a technical question. Is this the wrong place for those ?

Comment: Please, edit your post to clarify better the question and the TITLE. Yes, it's probably better if you ask this question on Stack Overflow or Data Science SE. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. Do you want me to migrate it to Data Science SE or Stack Overflow?

Comment: Thank you very much, yes that would be nice.

Comment: I will migrate it to Stack Overflow. If you don't receive help there, you may ask it later on Data Science SE.